# How to properly test php repositories

Tags: php, integration-testing, ddd-repositories

I'm trying to write integration tests for my repositories. For simple repositories this seems to be easy. I did something like this

```
class DBStatusRepositoryTest extends SmBaseIntegrationMemory
{
    private $dbStatusRepository;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->dbStatusRepository = new DBStatusRepository($this->dbConnection);
    }

    public function testShouldReturnAStatusEntity()
    {
        $status = $this->dbStatusRepository->getById(1);
        $this->assertInstanceOf('Acme\Modules\Foo\Model\Status', $status);
    }
}
```

Querying a the status repository should return a status entity.

But I'm not sure how to approach more complex repositories like this one:

```
public function testAddAttachment()
{
    $itemId = 420807;
    $user = new User([//** data ** //];
    $attachment = new Attachment();
    $attachment->setUser($user);
    $attachment->setSomething('something');
    $attachment->set....;

    $this->dbAttachmentRepository->addAttachmentForItem($itemId, $attachment);
    $attchments = $this->dbAttachmentRepository->getAllForLead($itemId);
    $this->assertCount(1, $attchments);
}
```

This piece of code is also testing all of the dependencies passed through. I am not sure this is ok.

Also when setting up the repository we could have a tree of dependencies like this:

```
$userRepository = new DBUserRepository($this->dbConnection);
$attachmentFactory = new AttachmentFactory($userRepository);
$this->dbAttachmentRepository = new DBAttachmentRepository($this->dbConnection, $attachmentFactory);
```

Is this the right approach to perform integration testing for repositories?

Update: To be more specific I'm already using DBUnit and in memory sqlite database that is being populated each time a test file runs. However, my question refers to whether is ok to instantiate all the dependencies required for some repository-related operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually as far as i understand, in an integration test, you would like to test your repository with real boundaries.

so instead of creating objects and putting them into repository,i would directly insert data in your database, test if you can get the data and delete it from the database.

you can do it manually or by using DBUnit

before each test you make direct inserts, store the inserted IDs, then use repository to retrieve the data and use the stored IDs to cleanup the database afterwards.

with DBUnit you can create XML/CSV/YAML files where you define the data and DBUnit make inserts and cleanups automatically for you.

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html

Comment: I am using in memory sqlite test database and dbunit and I'm populating the database with dummy data. However instead of reading the data, I want to test the insertion of data. Please see my second example above. My question is how to deal with repositories that have a tree of dependencies.

Comment: I just reflect my manual testing to PHPUnit. 

Lets assume you would not use Tests, how would you test your insertion? You would check the Database and see if there the expected entries. 

So after "addAttachmentForItem" i would just call plain SQL request to the specific tables and check for values. Maybe create before an expected stdClass for easier compensation

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing. 
$attchments = $this->dbAttachmentRepository->getAllForLead($itemId);
performs the query into the in-memory test database. Again, my question relates to Attachment entity and User entity! Why is the job of DBAttachmentRepositoryTest class to test/instantiate those?